# Error Message too long. regular expression validator, error message

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a registration form in asp.net and well I am new to coding, so i am using a Regular expression validator for password and the error message is pretty long. how do i make it in two lines or more.Thank you in advance !!

Comment: what exactly do you want. I mean what `length` should your password be or what should be the correct format to insert

Comment: use jquery validationEngine  for form validation it provide form validation both custom and built in.

Comment: @code Bug: Can you please post your HTML where you display error message ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of how to split a string or what is `Environment.NewLine`.... what have you tried/researched?

Answer (score 2):

What I understood is you want to restrict width of your error message. And If your error message is Too large then it should be split in one or more lines.

For that you should put your validator in `Div` tag and set `max-width` of the div.

See below code for `RequiredFieldValidator`

```
<div style="max-width: 100px">
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="textName" ErrorMessage="Very large error message. Very large error message. Very large error message. Very large error message. "></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
```